# artifacts-credprovider and VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS with Docker

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

Maybe you could help me with authentication with private NuGet feed, I already spend a day for different solutions and notice [this repo](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider), but I'm still struggling to make it done.

I'm using below Dockerfile with different variations, but I'm getting Unauthorized each time

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
ARG VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS
WORKDIR /api

#ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS={"endpointCredentials":[{"endpoint":"https://name.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Feed/nuget/v3/index.json","username":"PAT","password":"PAT"}]}


# Auth with private feed
RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh \
   && chmod +x installcredprovider.sh \
   && ./installcredprovider.sh


# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ["App.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /api
COPY --from=build /api/out ./
EXPOSE 4444
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "App.dll"]
```

I tried with ARGs and ENVs to set the VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS, but each time I'm getting this error:

`error NU1101: Unable to find package Package.Name. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org`

Currently we don't have dedicated NuGet.Config in the project, maybe it's the case of this issue?
That I need to create it and add this private repo to it?

Thank you.

Comment: yes, you need a nuget.config that tells NuGet what sources to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Nuget.config` is not required, but you need to specify source during restoring package, because, there is just default source (https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json)

Dockerfile (I modified environment variable):

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
#ARG VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS
WORKDIR /api

ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS '{"endpointCredentials":[{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/org/_packaging/feedname/nuget/v3/index.json","username":"name","password":"your personal access token"}]}'


# Auth with private feed
RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh \
   && chmod +x installcredprovider.sh \
   && ./installcredprovider.sh


# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ["App.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore -s "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/org/_packaging/feedname/nuget/v3/index.json" -s "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /api
COPY --from=build /api/out ./
EXPOSE 4444
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "App.dll"]
```

Comment: Thank you @starian chen-MSFT, you saved my day! Now it's working properly. I think there where two problems with my Dockerfile: 1) I didn't specify 'source' in the restore command and 2) It seems like I'm incorrectly used ENV declaration as well. Thanks!

Comment: I did the same but i could only 401  

.59 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.425/NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [/src/xyz.services.FnApp/xyz.services.FnApp.csproj]
------

Answer (score 3):

> Currently we don't have dedicated NuGet.Config in the project, maybe it's the case of this issue? That I need to create it and add this private repo to it?

Yes, you should create a `nuget.config` file in the same folder as your `Dockerfile` that is configured to use the private repo.

Then copy the `nuget.config` file in the `dockerfile`, like:

```
...
COPY . .
COPY NuGet.Config ./
...
```

And specify your private feed and Credentials in the `nuget.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="BredasVSTS" value="https://xxxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/BredasVSTS/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <BredasVSTS>
      <add key="Username" value="emailhere" />      
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="PAT here" />
    </BredasVSTS>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Check the document [Azure DevOps Private Nuget Feed with Docker Build](https://www.bradjolicoeur.com/Article/azure-devops-private-nuget-feed-with-docker-build) (step 4) and [Docker use private NuGet Feed](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6135#issuecomment-397847293) for some more details.