# Restoring from Azure Artefacts in CircleCI

Tags: azure, .net-core, circleci, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to restore from Azure Artefacts in CircleCI. I've been trying to piece together bits and pieces from [artifacts-credprovider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider), including the Docker image example. My circle CI config looks like this:

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install Artifacts Credprov
          command: |
            wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh | bash            
      - run:
          name: Restore Packages
          command: dotnet restore
      - run:
          name: Build
          command: dotnet build

workflows:
  main:
    jobs:
      - build
```

In the CircleCI Project I've also set the following env vars:

```
DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER=0
NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED-true
VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS={"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/paulgrenyer0243/_packaging/paulgrenyer0243/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"...", "password":"..."}]}
```

and when restoring this is the error I get:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
dotnet restore
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/NuGet.targets(124,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/paulgrenyer0243/_packaging/paulgrenyer0243/nuget/v3/index.json. [/root/repo/NugetClient.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/NuGet.targets(124,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [/root/repo/NugetClient.csproj]

Exited with code exit status 1
```

I'm assuming that either the env vars aren't being picked up, the env vars have the wrong values or I'm trying the wrong approach.

Does anyone have this working or can see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Restoring from Azure Artefacts in CircleCI

I agree with you. The dotnet restore task did not get the env vars from the CircleCI Project.

You could try to set the environment variable in a container, like:

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
        environment:
          VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS: {"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXX/_packaging/XXX/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"...", "password":"..."}]}
```

Then specify source during restoring package:

```
  - run:
      name: Restore Packages
      command: dotnet restore -s "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/XXX/_packaging/XXX/nuget/v3/index.json" -s "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"
```

You could check [this document](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-container) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362453/artifacts-credprovider-and-vss-nuget-external-feed-endpoints-with-docker) for some more details.

Hope this helps.